# Artificial intelligence related tags

Tags: support, tags

I was wondering why there do not seem to be any artificial intelligence related tags to choose from on the motor vehicle maintenance and repair site.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Usually when a tag doesn't exist, it's because nobody has asked a question concerning that particular line of thinking which the tag would denote. I'm sure there are thousands of tags which *could be* created if the right question was asked. If you have a question which concerns AI/ML as it pertains to MVM&R, I'd be happy to create the tag.

The only place I'm aware of where AI/ML is extensively used within the automotive realm is for self driving vehicles. There may be more innocuous AI/ML used elsewhere, but that's probably the big one.